# Request Parameters getting dropped

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, oracle11g, java

WE have a strange issue with our application. Some of the data appears and disappears from the application UI. The UI is developed using struts, hibernate , Spring. This is a sporadic event and can't be always reproduced. The next refresh of the page gets back the data.

I mean when we log into the web application the list of records are present on one instance. Sometimes these records are not present even when no one has modified or updated the information

The following are the environment components:
1. Oracle 11g
2. Oracle JDBC Driver 10.2.0.2.0
3. Tomcat 5.0.28
4. Linux: 2.6.9-100.Elhugemem (i386)
5. JVM 1.5.0_05-b05

Also we are using the same tablespace in Oracle to to host all users and we have many of them.

One new information on this. I have nailed it down to the request level. We set the parameters in request & somehow some of the request parameters are getting dropped, and all this happens intermittently.

Did anyone else have the same issue? If Yes? Was it resolved and what was the solution.

Comment: Is your environment clustered?

Comment: Please describe "some of the data appears and disappears" in more detail. This can be interpreted in so many ways.

Comment: I mean when we log into the web application the list of records are present on one instance. Sometimes these records are not present even when no one has modified or updated the information

Answer (score 0):

I never seen or even heard of Tomcat or Struts dropping request parameters, so maybe those parameters you think are dropped are never sent to the server in the first place.

If they are, than maybe Struts does not bring them in your action. You should check the definitions of your parameters in the ActionForm ( if you use Struts 1) or in the action (if you use Struts 2). A simple letter case difference ( say you have  'getTitle/setTitle' in your class and 'Title' instead of 'title' in your form ) will lead to problems.